# Select a portion of an area element based on a data range

Tags: d3.js

I have some data ranging from 2003 - 2007 plotted as a line graph using the following code:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });
```

and later when I've pulled my data in:

```
   x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
   y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);

  context.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("d", area);
```

I've implemented a brush to filter the data. It works like this one:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349545

But instead of a scatterplot, I have a line graph. I want to select arbitrary portions of the graph area and recolour it based on the brush selection. Just like the second graph on this yahoo chart:

http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=SAN.MC#symbol=san.mc;range=20040915,20131007;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;

I have a brush function that's fired on brushmove:

```
function brushmove() {
    var s = brush.extent();
    console.log(s);
}
```

which logs out the selected range correctly. I'm just not sure how to select a portion of my graph area based on the range coming back from the brushmove function.

Full code is here:

```
    //specify some margins
var margin = {top: 500, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
width = 960,
height = 100;

var bigMargin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
bigWidth = 960,
bigHeight = 400;

//parse the date 
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;



//create scales
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

//create scales
var bigX = d3.time.scale().range([0, bigWidth]),
bigY = d3.scale.linear().range([bigHeight, 0]);

//create axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var bigXAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(bigX).orient("bottom"),
bigYAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(bigY).orient("left");

//create a brush area accessor function
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
.x(x)

.on("brush", brushmove);




//create an area accessor function
var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

 var bigArea = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return bigX(d.date); })
.y0(bigHeight)
.y1(function(d) { return bigY(d.price); });

 //append the svg container
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
.attr("id", "clip")
.append("rect")
.attr("width", bigWidth)
.attr("height", bigHeight);

//append a container
var context = svg.append("g")
.attr('class','container')
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var bigContext = svg.append("g")
.attr('class','bigContainer')
.attr("transform", "translate(" + bigMargin.left + "," + bigMargin.top + ")");

//loop over the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

//coerce the data a little because values from .CSv are always strings
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
d.price = +d.price;
 });

//set the scale domains based on the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);

bigContext.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .attr("fill","red")
  .attr("d", bigArea);


//set the scale domains based on the data
bigX.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
bigY.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);

var t = new Date(2003, 0, 1);

//append the graph as an area
  context.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("d", area).
  attr("fill",function(d) { 
  //if the data is at a certain range then give it a particular fill
 return (new Date(d.date) > t ? "orange" : "yellow"); });



//append the x axis
context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


 //append the x axis
 context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
  .call(yAxis);


  //append the x axis
  bigContext.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + bigHeight + ")")
  .call(bigXAxis);



//append the x axis
 bigContext.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
  .call(bigYAxis);

//append the brush
context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x brush")
  .call(brush)
.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("y", -6)
  .attr("height", height + 7)



 });



function brushstart() {
    svg.classed("selecting", true);
}

function brushmove() {
    bigX.domain(brush.extent());
   bigContext.select("path").attr("d", bigArea);
  bigContext.select(".x.axis").call(bigXAxis);



}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html)?

Comment: Yes Similar but I want the selected region to be coloured and the rest of the grpah to be greyed out....exactly like the second graph on this page http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=SAN.MC#symbol=san.mc;range=20040915,20131007;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;

Comment: Did you have a look at the CSS for that graph? You should be able to do it by modifying the styles.

Comment: The CSS for which graph? The yahoo one I posted or the nvd3 one you posted? The yahoo one is flash. The nvd3 one is using nvd3 so not applicable to this instance. Basically I just need a way to select part of the area based on a date range...I'm sure it's possible - just can't find how to do it!

Comment: The NVD3 graph. Why is that not applicable?

Comment: It doesn't work in the way I want. It draws in masks - I kind of want the opposite where the brush acts as the mask. I've just found this which is exactly what I need http://square.github.io/crossfilter/  ...just seems a shame to use a plugin. I was thinking there might be a way that, given a date range, I could make a selection on my area (based on that data) and add a an alternate fill colour to that...

Comment: You could have a look at the source for crossfilter and extract the bits you need if that's doing exactly what you want it to do.